# Invalid length for a Base-64 array

Tags: c#

I have some lines of code where I get the error

> Invalid length for a Base-64 array

This code is written for login page:

```
int user = 0;

UserDT = UserAdapter.Select();

for (int i = 0; i < UserDT.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    byte[] bb = Convert.FromBase64String(UserDT.Rows[i]["Password"].ToString());
    string getpass = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bb);

    if (txtusername.Text == UserDT.Rows[i]["UserName"].ToString() && txtpassword.Text == getpass.ToString())
    {
        userid =Convert.ToInt32(UserDT.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString());
        uname = UserDT.Rows[i]["UserName"].ToString();
        user = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fine, but what is the problem here?

Comment: Well presumably it isn't a valid base64-string... there's not much more we can say about that, other than to hope you're not *really* storing passwords in plaintext and expecting base64 encoding to be any kind of encryption.

Comment: @JonSkeet i think i wrote password in manually in database and it was in plain text

Comment: @michasaucer, code is fine but i get an error msg Invalid lenght for a base-64 array

Comment: Dont store passwords as base64. Use a hash-algorithm like MD5 or SHA instead.

Comment: Well please *don't* store passwords in plain text to start with (it's horrible from a security standpoint)- and if you *are* doing so, why are you expecting them to be base64-encoded? Have you looked at what `UserDT.Rows[i]["Password"].ToString()` returns? Ideally, don't build you own authentication system at all - there are pluggable systems available all over the place.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry for that , actually i downloaded this project , i created the database and run storedprocedure , thats fine .. but when i go for login i need username and password , so i manually give a username and password

Comment: Okay, so you've put a password into the database that *isn't* base64-encoded, but the system expects that it *is* base64-encoded. That's the problem. You'll need to find a different way of adding the user to the database - I'd expect there to be instructions. I would be seriously worried about any sample code like this though.

Comment: @JonSkeet, that it you get me.. no dear there is not any instruction available for it

Comment: At the point where you've got no instructions and *definitely bad* code in terms of security, I'd strongly recommend running away from this project as quickly as possible.

Comment: @JonSkeet, but this project has same features what i really need.. well do you suggest any other project related to `Student Fees Management System`

Comment: @user6537157 MD5 is virtually equally bad (read: insecure) as plain text, SHA is good, salted SHA is better, [PKBDF2](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes) is best.

Comment: @RadhaKhare: No, I don't have any suggestions - but if this is intended to deal with *real financial data* I suspect there could be a legal liability for using software this insecure.

Comment: @ckuri MD5 is much better than plain. especially with unique salts for each password. But MD5 and SHA are not designed for password-hashing.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide the value that cause your error,

so check [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string) of the method `FromBase64String`

there is something about `length`:

> **FormatException**
>
> The length of `s`, ignoring white-space characters, is not zero or a multiple of 4.

so just check the length of your parameter for `FromBase64String`.